# Async ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, servicestack, asp.net-core-6.0, servicestack-text

From what I can tell ServiceStack.Text does not have async stream/writer support for serialization. In asp.net core 6 synchronous IO is disabled by default so if you want to use ServiceStack.Text as your JsonOutputFormatter your choices are

1. enable synchronous IO `AllowSynchronousIO = true`
2. serialize to a string then write async to the response stream

```
var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(context.Object);
await responseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json), httpContext.RequestAborted);
await responseStream.FlushAsync(httpContext.RequestAborted);
```

Which of the above two options is better?

Is there a third option?

Comment: Their documentation mentions supporting async/await here: https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client#using-c-asyncawait-friendly-apis - though I don't know if it applies to `ServiceStack.Text`

Comment: How are you using this and how is this related to ASP.NET Core 6? This isn't just about async operations. String allocations are more expensive. The ASP.NET Core stack uses System.Text.Json in a way that eliminates additional string allocations. If you serialize to a string, you end up allocating 100K extra strings for 100K responses.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ServiceStack.Text from our experience is faster than System.Text.Json, also it's the serialize we have been using for quiet a while now and we were not interested in switching. Our hope was to utilize ServiceStack.Text in a similar fashion to System.Text.Json where it wouldn't have to serialize to string and could instead write async to the stream. This question is about how you could do that if at all.

Comment: @odyth did you include the garbage collection overhead? Not just for SS, but *every* kind of code? String splitting when reading a 200K line CSV is 4-8 times slower than using regular expressions due to GC alone. Besides, I've seen ServiceStack benchmarks that claimed to be faster than Web API 1 except .... they used different test code for Web API and SS. Once you used the *same* code, Web Api was faster. The benchmarks were measuring themselves

Comment: @odyth my point wasn't about STJ but the ASP.NET Core stack itself. The combination of pipelines and Utf8JsonReader reduces allocations by orders of magnitude, resulting in the 5-10x perf increases we've seen. You'll have to ensure you *don't* allocate extra strings with ServiceStack.Text either. mythz's answer uses a buffered array to avoid one of the 2 buffer allocations, but it still allocates one extra string per request.

Comment: Besides, [System.IO.TextWriter.WriteAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeasync?view=net-8.0) already writes strings asynchronously. Why use `responseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)` when you can wrap the stream in a TextWriter and write the string to it directly?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because ServiceStack.Text writes synchronously, which throws an exception in asp.net core unless you enable AllowSynchronousIO. That was the point of the question is it better to enable AllowSynchronousIO and write synchronously to the text writer avoiding the extra allocation or serialize to a string then write async.

Comment: You're asking what's better, the rock or the hard place? We abandoned ServiceStack years ago for precisely this reason. You'll have to profile your application to see which is worse. Blocking operations are supposed to be short, so they start by spinwaiting,  pegging a core at 100%. Lots of allocations will eat a lot of RAM and CPU periodically. You can avoid some allocations by using StringBuffer, perhaps backed by a BufferPool. You can't avoid the 100% CPU usage caused by blocking. If you have lots or long IO operations, your request thread will be blocked for long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to a `string` then writing that asynchronously to a `Stream` is going to be more portable given it doesn't need to rely on external `AllowSynchronousIO` being enabled.

Although you can make this more efficient by using a `BufferPool` and `Memory<byte>` for the UTF8 conversion, e.g:

```cs
var buf = BufferPool.GetBuffer(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(json));
Memory<byte> bytes = buf;
await stream.WriteAsync(bytes[..Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json, bytes.Span)]);
BufferPool.ReleaseBufferToPool(ref buf);
```

Comment: is there any plans to support an async write operation to ServiceStack.Text so it could work in a similar fashion to System.Text.Json and just write direction to the stream?

Comment: No, all serializers are designed to synchronously write to a `TextWriter`, which you can use a backing `StreamWriter` to write to the underlying `Stream`. It would require a rewrite to change it for all writes to be asynchronous.

Comment: Why is this code necessary? The real overhead is allocating the `json` string. [TextWriter.WriteAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeasync?view=net-8.0) writes strings asynchronously so there shouldn't be a need for the byte array. I admit I haven't used ServiceStack in 5-6 years.

Comment: Not necessary, just more efficient. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)` allocates a new array to store the UTF8 encoded bytes, this example shows how to reuse arrays from the `BufferPool`.